# Receive index with jquery

Tags: jquery, indexing, css-selectors

While selecting the desired element is simple in jQuery i haven't found one way to receive an elements index
here's an example of what I want:

```
$('#minia .holder a').click(function () {
})
```

This function is used to catch any clicks on one of those elements
to catch that specific element I use $(this) now my question is how would i get
`$(this)` index so i can then later use it like so `$('#minia .holder a[index]')`.

Comment: Index of what?  Index of elements in the jQuery object?

Comment: well i want to be able to use the :eq(index) selector but to do that i need to somehow receive from the clicked element what index it has... you get my point?

Comment: What version of jquery? Getting an index in 1.4.1 is much easier.

Comment: i use 1.3
yeah i just discover that today :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved it by doing like this

```
 $('#pic .control').click(function () { 
         var imgUrl = $('#view').attr("src");
         var indexLink = $('#minia .holder a').index(jQuery('#minia .holder a[href="'+imgUrl+'"]')) + 1;
         $('#minia .holder a:eq('+indexLink+')').click();
      })
```

even thought you guys answered my initial question this was the final one

Comment: lol... okay.. good!!!.. and ever you wanted, I have updated my answer... :)) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try running this and get the idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").click(function () {
      // this is the dom element clicked
      var index = $("div").index(this);
      $("span").text("That was div index #" + index);
    });

  });
  </script>
  <style>
  div { background:yellow; margin:5px; }
  span { color:red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Click a div!</span>
  <div>First div</div>
  <div>Second div</div>
  <div>Third div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

a demo and documentation can be found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index).

**edit**

```
$('#pic .control').click(function () { 
     var imgUrl = $('#view').attr("src"); 
     // why not erase the next two lines... then
     //var indexLink = $('#minia .holder a').index('#minia .holder a[href="'+imgUrl+'"]'); 
     //$('#minia .holder a:eq('+indexLink+')').click(); 
     // use this 
     $('#minia .holder a[href="'+imgUrl+'"]').trigger('click'); // if you wanted a click..
})
```

Comment: darn i just tried it but i got 0 index each time

  $('#pic .control').click(function () { 
   var imgUrl = $('#view').attr("src");
   var indexLink = $('#minia .holder a').index('#minia .holder a[href="'+imgUrl+'"]');
   $('#minia .holder a:eq('+indexLink+')').click();
   })


this is the code

Comment: @Reigel: What is the point of pasting all the sample code from jQuery? Plus you should indicate you took the code from jQuery doc.

Comment: well idd this code would have been good if it hadnt been that i actually wanted to click the element comming after it

Comment: if you want the next one, you can use `.next()` like  `$('#minia .holder a[href="'+imgUrl+'"]').next().trigger('click');`   cheers! :))

Comment: well, you still have to choose an answer... :))

Comment: but will that work? considering the selector will only select elements having the link with that specifik image?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$('#minia .holder a').click(function (event) {

var temp_index = $(this).index();

})
```

Comment: var temp_index = $(this).index(this); // on jQuery 1.4.x